# After save dataframe to excel I can't open the excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I created dataframe, and use `df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False)`. I can see my python code generated excel file in a local directory, but problem is I can't open it with excel.

I also added more parameter `engine='xlsxwriter'` in `df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False)`. Thus I tried
`df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')`, but didn't work out.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('123.tsv', sep='\t')
df['M'] = df['M'].astype(str)
m = df.M.str.split(',', expand=True).values.ravel()
df = df.dropna()
df = df[~df.M.str.contains("@")]
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df.to_excel('123.xlsx', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')
```

expected outcome: just wanna open 123.xlsx in excel

actual result:

> Excel cannot open the file '123.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file. (Mac Excel 2016)

Comment: save the file as csv. Open the file with excel and you can save it as xlsx. Python does not provide full support for xlsx format.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with a similar problem, which did not exist when I was saving to csv. My file path is a onedrive pathway, I fixed it by replacing "write.save()" with "writer.close()" . The below example works for me:

```
f3 = input("Enter file path and name for saving the output file")    
filepath = Path(f"{f3}")    
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filepath)    
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1', index = False)    
df_2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2', index = False)
      
writer.close()
```

Comment: Welcome. If that is a similar problem with a solution of your own, then you are welcome to post it as a new question and answer. OP themselves have claimed issue concerned updating EXCEL. Your post will likely not be found here and not be as useful.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35171151)

Answer (score 0):

I'm responding some time later, but it may be helpful to someone

You may try by using an `ExcelWriter`, paying attention to include the `.close()`, which actually saves the file. In fact, as [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter) reports *"The writer should be used as a context manager. Otherwise, call close() to save and close any opened file handles."*

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('your_filename.xlsx'))
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='your_sheet_name')
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a late reply, but I'm having this problem when saving in OneDrive only (e.g. saving to c:\users\me\onedrive\folder\whatever.xlsx). If I save it to a non-Onedrive location (e.g. c:\work\whatever.xlsx). The following is the code I'm using:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("c:\\work\\whatever.xlsx") as writer:
    sheet1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet1")  
    sheet2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet2")  
writer.close()
```

I'm not 100% sure the final `writer.close()` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'path', engine='xlsxwriter')

df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name ='org_networks', index = False)
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name ='org_devices', index = False)
writer._save()
```

The excel file was created, saved and was able to open.

```
writer.close() also works but sometimes it locks the file!
```

Answer (score -1):

It should work as expected. I tried your program with the following sample input (tab separated):

```
M   L
foo 123
bar 456
baz 789
```

And was able to open the output `123.xlsx` file:

[image]

Can you try this simple input and see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

It is excel issue after I updated it. Please close this issue stackoverflow team. Thank you.